# SQLite query give different result from mysql

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have two table in my sqlite db here is the first table named `supplier`[image] and here is the second table named `product` [image]

what I want to do is I want to get the `supplier_name` in `table product` by selecting `id_supplier` in `table_product`. Here is my query `SELECT table_supplier.id_supplier, table_supplier.supplier_name from table_invoice_in, table_supplier where table_invoice_in.id_product = '4' and table_supplier.id_supplier = table_invoice_in.id_supplier`

and what I got from that query is I can get the `id_supplier` but `supplier_name` gives me `0` value, but when I try the query in mysql, I got the correct result. My question is :

1. Is this a limitation of sqlite or there are something wrong with my query?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: try: SELECT Supplier.Name FROM Suppler INNER JOIN Product ON Suppler.Id = Product.SupplierId WHERE Product.Id = '4'

Comment: Your query is bad - `and table_supplier.id_supplier = table_invoice_in.id_supplier` how does the query know which row of table_supplier to use?  I'm surprised that SQL Management Studio let you run this query and that you didn't get an exception when running code to execute this query.

Comment: @Simon if it is bad why it is work in mysql?

Comment: The query looks correct, and there is no limitation. Your data is wrong.

Comment: @ClearEyes thank you for helping me, but your query seem doesn't work

Comment: @CL. Am I need to add `LIMIT` to my query?

Comment: No, you need to check the data in your tables.

Comment: @CL. I don't think my data is wrong because I clone the db and put it on mysql and I got the correct result as I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved! When we try to query some column(s) from multiple table, make sure that we get the desired result by pointing directly to the column name. Here is my correct code

```
public Cursor SelectInvoiceInById(String id){
    String query = "SELECT product_name from table_product, table_invoice_in where table_invoice_in.id_invoice_in = '"+ id + "' and table_product.id_product = table_invoice_in.id_product";
    ReadDB();
    cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
            Log.d("RESULT", String.valueOf(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.PRODUCT_NAME))));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    CloseDB();
    return cursor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a JOIN:

```
SELECT table_supplier.id_supplier, table_supplier.supplier_name FROM table_supplier JOIN table_invoice_in ON table_supplier.id_supplier = table_invoice_in.id_supplier WHERE table_invoice_in.id_product = '4'
```

Comment: Good idea in general, but this has exactly the same semantics and does not answer the question.

Comment: @BitwiseCreative I tried you query but it still return the same result as I am. Thank you any way.